# How to fix vulnerabilities in semver and expo@44.0.6 in npm audit report?

Tags: npm, expo, semantic-versioning, npm-audit

I'm facing security vulnerabilities in my npm audit report, specifically related to semver (versions 7.0.0 - 7.5.1) and expo@44.0.6, both rated as moderate severity.

Here are the details from the npm audit report:

audit report:
semver  7.0.0 - 7.5.1
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@44.0.6, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@expo/image-utils/node_modules/semver
@expo/image-utils  >=0.3.10-alpha.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
node_modules/@expo/image-utils
@expo/prebuild-config  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/image-utils
node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config
@expo/cli  >=0.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/prebuild-config
node_modules/@expo/cli
expo  >=45.0.0-beta.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/cli
node_modules/expo

5 moderate severity vulnerabilities

I've already tried running "npm audit fix --force," but it seems to introduce more issues than it resolves. After that command, I end up with 7 moderate and even 9 high severity vulnerabilities.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve these vulnerabilities without upgrading to expo@49.0.4. I prefer to keep expo@44.0.6 if possible, as updating to expo@49.0.4 might cause other compatibility issues.

Additionally, I suspect that some packages may be interdependent, and updating one might create further problems. Should I consider downgrading certain packages to a version where the vulnerabilities are not present?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your support!